# How to combine Unicode characters

Tags: java, android, unicode, urdu

I am doing a project that is Roman to Urdu Transliteration. The problem is that I want to transliterate a Roman Urdu string into Unicode transliteration. So what is the exact way to do this?

How to combine Unicode characters?

Comment: This is the latest code that I wrote my self.

Comment: It would help if you provide the exact problem you have. What part of the code is not working or unclear to you? What do you mean by "How to combine Unicode characters"? You have a problem concatenating strings? With what exactly do you need help.

Comment: I cannot post my code it too much long.

Comment: Yes, the problem is to concatenating Unicode characters in java.

Comment: Have you ever used "Google  Urdu input tool"  ? I want to do the transliteration process as they have done.

Comment: @PeterParker Can you please help me?